# Scala:Splitting a line and count the number of words

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and learning scala...

```
val pair=("99","ABC",88)
pair.toString().split(",").foreach { x => println(x)}
```

This gives the splitted line. But How do I count the number of splitted words .

I am trying as below:

```
pair.toString().split(",").count { x => ??? }
```

I am not sure how can I get the count of splitted line. ie 3  ..

Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pair.toString().split(",").size` will give you the number of elements.  OTOH, you have a `Tuple3`, so its size will only ever be three.  Asking for a `size` function on a tuple is rather redundant, their sizes are fixed by their type.

Plus, if any of the elements contain a comma, your function will break.

Comment: @Ryan....Thanks ..I just missed it.....I was only concentrating on count methos....

Answer (score 4):

Tuples are equipped with product functions such as `productElement`,    `productPrefix`, `productArity` and `productIterator`for processing its elements.

Note that

```
pair.productArity
res0: Int = 3
```

and that

```
pair.productIterator foreach println
99
ABC
88
```